# Comparing Hive to Pig for usability on structured data

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

We just started on Pig recently and are having a challenge figuring out its syntax on structured data. Given the example datamodel below, which would be a better fit for the problem, Hive or Pig, or "Other"?

Data Model:

```
Item
 > id<long>
 > description<string>
 > source<collection of following>
     > source_id<long>
     > source_name<string>
     > relevant_link<collection of strings>
         > link_id<string>

Link
 > link_id<string>
 > metadata1<string>
 > metadata2<string>
```

*Common operations:*

- Import data from various formats to this format
- Query (sort, aggregate, sample, summarize) data (preferrably by a team who won't all be experts in the language)
- Join and export in various formats with various filters

This is basic data manipulation of a large dataset (150-500 GB raw text data).

*Issues / Questions:*

- Pig has posed us a challenge in joining on that link (collections of collections in pig are bags of bags which become quite abstract).
- Is Hive good/better at managing these collections of collections?
- We expect a lot of "data transformation" activities, but since we can easily fit our data in a SQL-like format, does this make Hive an easier-to-use solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Pangool](http://pangool.net/), Map Reduce code is in Java and it simplifies work with structured data, relies on notion of tuples and serialization. For your particular case you could use [Custom Serialization](http://pangool.net/userguide/custom_serialization.html) with Avro objects which are basically JSON.
It also simplifies writing reduce side joins and multiple inputs which need to be processed by different mappers.

So one Pangool mapper for Link which emits link_id as a key and another Pangool mapper for Item which emits link_id with itself. But it could be slow.

If map side join is possible (link file is small enough for memory) you could put it into Serializable Java objects in main code and pass it to the mapper, it makes life very easy.

Comment: Very interesting, I wasn't aware of this, thanks for suggesting it!